# What effect does tire size have?

Tags: snowrunner

Tires come in multiple sizes, but the wheel performance across the sizes always appears to be identical. I'm assuming there's some difference between them, but I can't find any information in the codex. I could try experimenting with different tire sizes, but unfortunately I'm still early enough in the game that money is too tight for me to afford buying multiple sets of tires just for the sake of SCIENCE!

What effect does tire size have?

Comment: In real life, from what I understand, bigger tires give you more ground clearance, more traction, and increased cool factor in exchange for a slight reduction in steering response. In game though, I'm not sure which of these effects apply other than ground clearance and cool factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So now that I've been playing for a bit, I can safely say that tire size makes a huge difference.

The most significant difference is that larger tires have a much easier time getting through mud, snow, and water. Cars with larger tires will get through this terrain quicker, and is much less likely to get stuck as well. The difference is large enough that mud which would completely trap your vehicle with a smallest tire size can be driven through with ease on the largest tile size. Additionally, it would appear that larger tires allow you to go through deeper patches of water without taking engine damage.

Another benefit to larger tires is that that larger tires have an easier time driving over rocks, slopes and other obstacles you come across in the terrain. Larger tires are also faster than smaller ones, although this does mean you need to be more careful about watching your speed (so you don't flip over).

The main downside to larger tires that I've seen is that larger tires appear to be less stable than smaller ones. I'm basing this primarily on my experience with the Chevy 1500. The Chevy with the largest tire size is much more prone to flipping over than when it's equipped with a smaller tire. In fact, I was never concerned about flipping the Chevy over until I upgraded to a larger tire, after which I started flipping over constantly (compared to the zero times I flipped it over before). I suspect, although haven't confirmed, that the difference in stability depends on the vehicle.

Luckily, you don't just need to take my word for it, since YouTuber [SD1ONE](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-3YVzX5LZ6QHFnv_CmAHAA) has done several tests with tires, including the effect of tire size. His video confirms most of the benefits of larger tires I've outlined above, although it doesn't really touch on the decreased stability.

Comment: Lower stability does make a lot of sense: your center of gravity is higher with bigger tires.

Answer (score -1):

I apologize for being a necro post. But i just came across this. Not sure about tire size. IRL larger tires reduce rpm and require more HP to turn them. In game it seems like my trucks get moving slower with larger tires but overall they work better in all terrain. They shouldn't effect stability though. If anything it might help because they are wider and a 38" tire isn'tabnormally big on a truck. On my work truck the tires are 47" and if anything im more stable. The nature of tires are to keep u stable. Now the height of the body and suspention will effect stability my work truck is a 6×6 military truck known as a duece and a half. Even at its height its pretty stable because of the wide wheel base. It is very similar to the ANK MK38 in game. Which is one of the best trucks in game too.. What does effect stability in game and IRL is a lift kit. I didn't flip anything until I raised my trucks. Now have to be far more aware if I'm sideways on a slope. I've had to use my winch in a few spots to keep from flipping. Keep the winch tight and keep your truck in low range so u don't outrun the winch. This game needs a winch that can reverse to. In fact all winches reverse IRL. How else do u pick up all the cable u unspool. Both winches on my jeep outside reverse and have neutral. Which is typical. The dude talking about flipping all the time because of bigger tires. Did u put a lift kit on the suspension? If so that's why your flipping. I never flipped with big tires alone. I flipped once turning to hard after lifting it. That's it and I'm speaking about the pick up. A few things the developers can do to get more realism is allowing u to have more than 1 winch on your trucks and the winches need to have spool out and spool in and a neutral. In real life I've had to use both winches on my truck to get thru a few spots before on my way to a jobsite. Without both winches I would have been stuck. I'm a welder/mechanic and do a lot of heavy equipment repair and often the jobs it's I go to are in the middle of nowhere. Especially logging and exploratory drilling. Not oil. Not in my state. They drill mostly to check ground water and to take soil samples among other stuff. On occasion I have to rescue them. So my work truck is big. It a old military truck called a duece and a half. I did some modifications to it to make it a work truck that can carry heavy ass welding machines cutting torches hand tools various pieces of steel nuts and bolts etc. So it has to carry some weight in harsh terrain. Anyways I have a winch on the front and rear and my rear winch is movable. I welded some rreicevers for it on the sides of my truck and on my trailer.

Comment: Hi there and welcome! It appears you may have posted content here that is better suited for a discussion forum rather than on Arqade. Arqade is all about getting answers; we are not a discussion forum and there is no chit-chat. Answers are expected to relate directly to the question and provide a full answer or a partial thereof, without tangenting into related topics. If you would prefer to write about your own experiences, a different site would be better suited for you. For more information, please see our [tour page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).